# Having a weird bug with mongrel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mongrel

This is from the development log...

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:101:in `dispatch_cgi'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Apr 15 20:19:18 +0000 2010
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Is this the entire stack trace OR are there any missing pieces?

Comment: the rest of the log just repeats exactly as shown above

Answer (score 1):

This i guess is a simple case of there not being a database configured. Create a database first using:  `rake db:create:all`

Comment: you were right - i made a rookie mistake in the database config file.  Thanks paddy!

Comment: btw.. switch to passenger. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the params hash that is sent from the form (or the form input names) ? The issue might be related of Rails's inability to parse a mixed array-hash values. PS I don't find the question obnoxious, aside the huge paste (arguable somewhat necessary)

Me sure you don't send in the request a mixed array hash value as rails will complain, ie.:

```
user[][name] => joe              # array-ish
user[:key][name] => alice        # hash-ish
```

both in the same request.